# Get variables from mongodb find() results

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a mongodb find() that gets me the two latest entries in my database for use in my php code. I've so far only needed to work with one entry, below is the code getting the timestamp, latitude and longitude variables from the latest entry.

Can anyone suggest the best way to get the same variables for the second entry? I tried accessing like an array with "$document[0]" but I think its keyed by name. Thanks for any help!

```
    //sort in descending order (time), pick first 2 entries
    $options = ['sort' => ['Time' => -1], 'limit' => 2];
    $filter=[];
    $cursor = $collection->find($filter, $options);

    //get the latest entry (biggest unix timestamp)
    $largest =  0;
    foreach($cursor as $document){
       if ($largest < $document["Time"]) {
       $largest = $document["Time"];
       $longitude = $document["Longitude"];
       $latitude = $document["Latitude"];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out an inelegant way of doing it by repeating everything with 'skip 1' but for lack of anything else:

```
$options = ['sort' => ['Time' => -1], 'limit' => 2, 'skip' => 1];
  $cursor = $collection->find($filter, $options);
  //initialize variables containing the previous entry data
  $largest2 =  0;
  foreach($cursor as $document){
   if ($largest2 < $document["Time"]) {
       $largest2 = $document["Time"];
       $longitude2 = $document["Longitude"];
       $latitude2 = $document["Latitude"];
        }
}
  echo  nl2br ("\n previous entry");
  echo  nl2br ("\n $latitude2");
  echo  nl2br ("\n $longitude2");
  echo  nl2br ("\n $largest2");
```